# fastai ulmfit model trained on cuda machin for cpu

Tags: gpu, cpu, fast-ai

I have an `export.pkl` model which has been trained on a cuda machine. I want to use it on a macbook:

```
from fastai.text import load_learner
from utils import get_corpus

learner = load_learner('./models')
corpus = get_corpus()

res = [ str(learner.predict(c)[0]) for c in corpus ]
```

I get the following error:

```
  ...
  File "/Users/gautiergilabert/Envs/cc/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 146, in forward
    "them on device: {}".format(self.src_device_obj, t.device))
RuntimeError: module must have its parameters and buffers on device cuda:0 (device_ids[0]) but found one of them on device: cpu
```

I have two questions:

- I found the `raise` in my `export.pkl`:

```
for t in chain(self.module.parameters(), self.module.buffers()):
    if t.device != self.src_device_obj:
        raise RuntimeError("module must have its parameters and buffers "
                           "on device {} (device_ids[0]) but found one of "
                           "them on device: {}".format(self.src_device_obj, t.device))
```

It is said about the module in the docstring: `module to be parallelized`. I don't really understand what it is. My macbook ?

Apart my macbook, I would like to run the model on a cpu

- Is there a way to make this `export.pkl` model works on a cpu ?
- Is there a way to make another `export.pkl` on cuda and make it available on a cpu ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way is to load the learner by specifying the model with empty dataset and loading the model weights afterwards. For resnet image classifier something like this should work:

```
from fastai.vision import *

# path where the model is saved under path/models/model-name
path = "model_path"

tfms = get_transforms()
data = ImageDataBunch.single_from_classes(".", classes=["class1", "class2"], ds_tfms=tfms)

learner = cnn_learner(data, models.resnet34, metrics=accuracy)
# loads model from model_path/models/model_name.pth
learner.load("model_name")

image = open_image("test.jpg")
pred_class, pred_idx, outputs = learner.predict(image)
```